# Stack Overflow topic-specific sites

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I recently discovered http://agileshout.com, a Stack Overflow implementation focused on questions about Agile.

The site has fairly low traffic, it seems, but it also seems very new. I'm wondering what the value of a topic-specific Stack Overflow-like site offers. Why would I go to that site instead of looking at the questions with the [agile](/questions/tagged/agile) tag on SO?

The broader question is — what value do topic-specific Stack Overflow sites have? I could see it within a company firewall, but not for public use.

Comment: An agile question? This one has escaped me!

Comment: Also, nice use of 'hath'.

Comment: is this *very clever* spam? :)

Comment: @JohnIdol - You get the "spam spotter" badge for that.

Comment: @Aiden I edited out "hath" because it's for singulars.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the founders can explain some use cases and answer your question in his tech talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ

Answer (score 0):

on a topic-specific site most likely people who know something about that specific topic will be hanging out.  Not everyone who is on SO answering questions will know about agile, but most likely people answering questions on agileshout will know something about it.

Comment: By extension, does that mean having one stackexchange per StackOverflow tag would be a good thing? Yeah, I know, I'm pushing it to the extreme but well, not every Java developer will know about C# (but may want to see C# questions without having to browse another site though). Sadly, this is my feeling with Agile which is programming related. I'd prefer to not have to go on another website for site.

Answer (score 0):

It is a business model - SO and others are part of a question/answer site brand, and the more the merrier (advertisement etc)l.

Answer (score 0):

Only of use within a firewall?

The guys at http://epicadvice.com/ would disagree, no doubt :)

See  https://stackexchange.com/ for what Joel and Jeff are up to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for migrating the question here. I didn't know this site existed.

And no, it hath not the qualities of spam. I have no affiliation or interest in the other site. I just happened to stumble upon it and it raised the question: "Where should I engage the agile community?"

Kristen's response in my original question clarified some things for me - that separate StackOverflow sites can be used effectively for non-tech issues (e.g. Fatherhood, Beer-making). My confusion was more in those that try to fork tech-relevant topics into their own sites (like the agile folks).

Thanks.